# Once an archer looses an arrow, does the arrow still use the archer's saves as though it were attended?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, saving-throw

The title pretty much says it all – let’s say there is an effect that can destroy objects. If an archer fires an arrow and it intersects this effect, does the arrow get to use the archer’s saves until it reaches its destination, or does it just count as an unattended item at that point?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Carrying, Movement and Exploration](http://www.dndsrd.net/carryingAndExploration.html#object-saving-throws) defines attended as:

> An item attended by a character (being grasped, touched, or worn)...

The arrow, while in flight, is none of those, so it's unattended. Only if the archer uses a magic arrow, does the item receive a save anyway. ([Enchanted bows bestow their properties](http://www.dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#ranged-weapons-and-ammunition) upon their ammunition, but the arrows only count as magical for the purposes of damage reduction).

Comment: Thanks. This is coming up in concern to how Vow of Peace works with its effect of shattering manufactured weapons that contact the character.